# Retrieve JSON object from firebase database in JSON format and bind to jquery grid using foreach

Tags: jquery, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I m new to Node js and firebase. I m trying to fetch JSON data stored in my firebase database depending upon some search criteria.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvYIg.png)

```
firebase.database().ref('/ChatRequests/Ks3Z3ybnjklutyiu/').on('value', function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {

            var Original= JSON.stringify(childSnapshot.val().Original);
            var uppercase= JSON.stringify(childSnapshot.val().uppercase);
                $('#dataGrid').columns({
                    data: [
                        {
                            "Original": Original, "uppercase": uppercase,
                        }]
                });
            });
        });
```

Want to bind all data to jquery grid but here just binding only first record.Pls Help

Answer (score 0):

do you need the `JSON.stringify` ? the values are already strings. e.g. "sample".
and you use `.Original` but your key is `original` in the screenshot. (in lowercase)
maybe these help.